# Best way to save money doing money exchange

Tags: foreign-exchange

First of all I apologize for my bad English. I will try my best here to explain my current situation.

Next week I will travel to Germany for work, and I will stay for some days.  The company gave me some extra money (in euros) that I can spend the way I want. The thing is, when I come back to Brazil on the next day I will get my vacation so I will travel to the US!

I decided to spend this extra money in the US so my question is:
Is it better to exchange the euros for dollars in Germany or should I keep it and exchange it when I get to US?

Comment: Sadly your English is better than some native speakers.  I hope you enjoy your stay in the US.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to see this [question and its answers.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51000/whats-the-best-way-to-exchange-euro-to-usd)  If it was me, I'd prefer to exchange the currency in Germany.  Why?  When you are in the US you will be on vacation.  It does not seem fun to spend vacation time in a bank.

Comment: Hum...  You are right, I didn´t think that way! Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Your welcome.  I would also advise against changing in your home country as it might be a crazy time.  Your flight from Germany might be delayed, you might need to buy somethings for you trip, doing laundry exc...